Understanding ==
I was creating a code for my homework and I was using Python as my language but there's something I don't understand in this example code's output:
def numbers (num):

    remove = str(num)[:-1]
    remove += str(int(remove) %7)
    return int(remove) == num

numb = int (input("Enter a 6 Digit Number: "))
print(numbers(numb))

The part I don't understand is why does it say True when I input: 123454

You can use print to show the value of variables or expressions at each step to better understand what happens.

what do expect it to say?

What do you expect?  The code does exactly what I would expect looking at it.  But the only math that is done here is 12345 % 7, mostly you're dealing with strings.

You return int(remove) == num which is an equality check that obvoiusly will give you a boolean. what you expect

Code which doesn't do what you want is a bad way to explain what you actually want. The code you wrote returns the value of a comparison, which is a boolean; we can't guess what you wanted it to return, or why you hoped for this code to return something else.

int(remove) == num is a comparison, it's like asking the question "are these two things equal?" ... the result is a boolean value, either True or False ...these are like answering "yes" or "no" to the question of whether the values are equal

or was your question about why the math works out so that 123454 returns True while other values would return False?

    # 1. str(123454)      -> "123454" - decimal representation of a number
    # 2. "123454"[:-1]    -> "12345"  - deleting 1 last character
    # 3. int("12345")     -> 12345    - conversion to an integer
    # 4. 12345 % 7        -> 4        - division remainder: 12345 - 1763 * 7
    # 5. str(4)           -> "4"      - decimal representation of a number
    # 6. "12345" += "4"   -> "123454" - appending a string to a string
    # 7. int("123454")    -> 123454   - conversion to an integer
    # 8. 123454 == 123454 -> True     - comparing integers

